# Surviving different physics?

Tags: science-based, technology, physics

I was thinking of a scenario in which humanity finds a universe with radically different laws of physics such that if a person was to simply step into this universe, he/she would be killed by the differences in the laws of physics.  This universe does have life in it, though, but the life in this universe is very different from the life in our universe.

While humans could not naturally survive in this hypothetical universe, would there be a way to use advanced technology to survive in this universe despite the laws of physics?

Comment: What are the laws of physics in this universe?

Comment: How do you "find a universe"? I pretty sure that everywhere is this universe.

Comment: Carry a bubble of this universe's space-time with you into the new universe. That's predicated on the laws not being so different that space-time itself as we know it cannot exist in the universe.

Comment: Without picking a specific set of laws of physics (and more difficult, the laws of physics in play during the process of crossing over to this universe), this is pretty hopeless to try to answer, and I'm not entirely sure how to nail down the physics in question without crossing the line into "idea generation."  One thing to consider: you talk about "radically different laws of physics."  If you do some research, even "just slightly different laws of physics" can render a place inhospitable using any known tehcnology (i.e. atoms instantly fall apart... game over)

Comment: As a trivial consideration:  Pick an approach X for surviving in a universe with radically different laws of physics.  Now imagine a universe where X cannot possibly work (for example, X requires atoms).  You have now constructed a new radically different set of laws of physics which nullify X.

Comment: our universe **could** be just a small bubble in a sheet of bubble wrap, no two bubbles are identical is what you are saying. Mathematics should be generic maybe each universe had different set of constants and maybe in one of such universe there is no CP violation so without surplus of matter nothing not even life can exist, what I'm saying is your OP is too broad ;)

Answer (score 2):

For example, let's use Universe A (native) and Universe B (foreign)

In order to survive, it may take technology from the one you wish to travel to for you to survive. Likely, it would be a one-way trip.

You could also say they consist of a different number of dimensions.

Let's say your pencil sketch is a 2D creature. If it was alive, and you could somehow remove it, a few things could or would happen. 
Primarily, the 2D creature would collapse, lacking muscles to hold itself together in a new dimension.

Now, using the same example... A human could attempt to draw a ship or frame or something to reinforce the 2D entity.

Even if it could work, it wouldn't be fun. Sensory overload, pain, insanity, instant death, would all be possible, and if it wasn't a one-way trip, it would all happen again when the creature returned.